# Sometimes Linear layout background color gets changed automatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a main layout. This layout is inflated to the fragment. I have layout named "default_layout_item". The main layout has a header bar, whose background color is blue. Below that there is a listview. Listview item background color is set to white in getview .

Everything works fine The problem what I'm facing is, sometimes header bar color gets changed to white. It's not a part of listview. Then why its happening

Is anyone facing the similar problem? Thanks in Advance..

Comment: put your code here, that wil help figure out issue

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of possible issues. Though I would strongly urge you to proof read future questions.. to make it easier on us. Simple thought organization goes a long way.

Following I don't understand most of your question, but I think I might know what you are looking for.. It sounds like you are having issues with the fact Android recycles views in a list view. IE it doesn't actually make a view for every item in a list (if it goes over the screen length) that would be bad. Instead it only makes as many as the screen shows.

To get the correct background you want to set it in your getView in your custom adapter code.

IE

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    //logic for figuring out the color here. Followed by the code to set it.
    return rowView;
  }
```

All you need will be in http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

I changed the color in this case when I was doing multiple selections on a very custom widget.

If you are trying to set a general color, you should be learning about styles and themes.

Comment: I think you didnt get my question... I have a header bar, whose background color is blue. Below that there is a listview. Listview item background color is set to white. The problem what I'm fscing is, sometimes header bar color gets changed to white. It's not a part of listview. Then why its happening